A lemma of Cielsielski
Reading section 2 of this paper '' A century of Sierpinski–Zygmund functions'' (Ciesielski, K.C., Seoane-Sepúlveda, J.B.. Rev. R. Acad.Cienc. Exactas Fis. Nat. Ser. A Mat. RACSAM 113(4), 3863–3901 (2019)), i wonder if some conditions requested were really necessary.
For example to page 6 why i esclude rational point from $P_f$? ($P:=P_f\setminus\mathbb{Q}$) and why considered a countable basis of $\mathbb{R}$ of nonempty intervals with rational
endpoints. I don't find it useful to talk about rational numbers in this case.
Most important: in first part of lemma 2.3 what are the sets $\hat U$ and $\hat V$ for?
I have proof that if i considered $x\in P\cap \hat B$ and $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{U}\cup\{U_0\times V:V\in\mathcal{W}\}$ ($\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{U}$ if $\mathcal{W}=\emptyset$) then are satisfied the above properties b),c) and $Y\cap B\neq \emptyset$.
I have difficulty verifying  property a); can someone help me?
enter image description here

Welcome to the site. You should provide necessary context, rather than leaving it in an image. Take the time to Latex what is relevant so users can see what's going on
